# Spark/pySpark: Best way to read small binary data files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I need to read data from binary files. The files are small, of the order of `1 MB`, so it's probably not efficient to use `binaryFiles()` and process them file by file (too much overhead).

I can join them in one big file and then use `binaryRecords()`, but the record size is just `512 bytes`, so I'd like to concatenate several records together, in order to produce chunks of the size of tens of megabytes. The binary file format allows this.

How can I achieve this?
More in general: Is this the right approach to the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As of Spark 2.1, `binaryFiles()` will coalesce multiple small input files into a partition (default is 128 MB per partition), so using `binaryFiles()` to read small files should be much more efficient now.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/51460293/215945 for more details about `binaryFiles()` and how to adjust the default 128 MB size (if desired).

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure, but this way might help:

N is the number of your small files.

rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to N, N).mapPartitions(binaryFiles()).collect()