# PySpark: Partitioning while reading a binary file using binaryFiles() function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, binaryfiles, partitioning

```
sc = SparkContext("Local")
rdd = sc.binaryFiles(Path to the binary file , minPartitions = 5).partitionBy(8)
```

or

```
sc = SparkContext("Local")
rdd = sc.binaryFiles(Path to the binary file , minPartitions = 5).repartition(8)
```

Using either of the above codes, I am trying to *make 8 partitions in my RDD {wherein, I want the data to be distributed evenly on all the partitions}*. When I am printing **{rdd.getNumPartitions()}**, the number of partitions shown are 8 only, but on **Spark UI**, I have observed that though 8 partitions are made but the all the whole binary file data is put on only one partition.

Note: **minPartition** attribute is not working. Even after setting minPartitions = 5,the number of partitions made in RDD is 1 only. Thus, used partitionBy/repartition Functions.

Is this is the desired behaviour or Am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Spark 2.4+**, the problem should be fixed, see @Rahul's comment below this answer.

**Spark 2.1-2.3**, the `minPartitions` argument of `binaryFiles()` is ignored.  See [Spark-16575](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16575) and the [commit changes to function setMinPartitions()](https://github.com/ThySinner/spark/commit/db414bc54a89072a458d1700eeb100e0212b80a5#diff-ab34ed7b74928b135dc1e4a398c44c05R46).  Notice in the commit changes how `minPartitions` isn't used anymore in the function!

If you are reading multiple binary files with `binaryFiles()`, the input files will be coalesced into partitions based on the following:

- `spark.files.maxPartitionBytes`, default 128 MB
- `spark.files.openCostInBytes`, default 4 MB
- `spark.default.parallelism`
- the total size of your input

The first three config items are described [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#execution-behavior).  See the commit change above to see the actual calculation.

I had a scenario where I wanted a max of 40 MB per input partition, hence 40 MB per task... to increase parallelism while parsing.  (Spark was putting 128 MB into each partition, slowing down my app.)  I set `spark.files.maxPartitionBytes` to 40 M before calling `binaryFiles()`:

```
spark = SparkSession \
   .builder \
   .config("spark.files.maxPartitionBytes", 40*1024*1024)
```

For only one input file, @user9864979's answer is correct: a single file cannot be split into multiple partitions using just `binaryFiles()`.

---

When reading multiple files with **Spark 1.6**, the `minPartitions` argument does work, and you have to use it.  If you don't, you'll experience the [Spark-16575](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16575) problem: all of your input files will be read into only two partitions!

You will find that Spark will normally give you fewer input partitions than you request.  I had a scenario where I wanted one input partition for every two input binary files.  I found that setting `minPartitions` to "the # of input files * 7 / 10" gave me roughly what I wanted.
I had another scenario where I wanted one input partition for each input file.  I found that setting `minPartitions` to "the # of input files * 2" gave me what I wanted.

**Spark 1.5** behavior of `binaryFiles()`: you get one partition for each input file.

Comment: Great answer. It looks like this is being fixed in spark 2.4 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22357). Meanwhile, setting spark.files.maxPartitionBytes to a low value seems to be the workaround to coax spark to use multiple partitions.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** That's the expected behavior.

Since you read file with `binaryFiles` a whole content of the file is loaded as a single record, and single records cannot be split across multiple partitions. There is simply nothing to distribute here.

Comment: But as per the Spark's Official Documentation, minPartition argument in the binaryFiles() function determines the minimal splitting number for input data. Thus, if minPartitions is set to 5, then the input data should be splitted into minimum five partitions. Right?

Comment: @user_19 Not really. It determines minimum number of partitions. It doesn't say that partitions will be non-empty or data will be evenly distributed between partitions. If you had at least num-partitions files, then you could expect more uniform distribution (without any guarantees in practice). If you want distribute data,  with a single input file, you're using wrong function.

Comment: As of Spark 2.1, the `minPartitions` argument is ignored--see my answer.